# Ajax requests to ASP.NET handler limited

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to test a **notification handler** web application which has 2 endpoints:

- one for long polling where clients register
- one for handling the incoming notifications.

I wrote a test script in `test.html` for polling with multiple clients and a script in `business.html` for sending the notifications.

The problem is that when I start 5 clients it works fine, but **when I start 6 or more clients The `business.html` won't load until I stop the requests**.

I tried to change the asp.net config files as suggested [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268) but it didn't help.

Are there any request limits that should be changed elsewhere?

The polling and adding of the notifications are done with simple jquery ajax calls to the `notificationhandler.ashx` and `addnotification.ashx`.

Comment: wrong choice of technology for long polling! try node.js instead

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008

Comment: IIS on windows 7 has a limitation on the connection that can be served. Windows Server has no limitations.